# Copy a directory, if already exist in target place need to copy another place using shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I am new in shell scripting..
Trying to copy a directory..
If destination have same directory.. need to ask there directory already exist,to copy another destination place. using shell scripting....

Comment: My advice is to manually execute this on the command line first. Figure out how each command works. Shell scripting isn't magical. Read the man pages for the 'cp' command and for the 'if' command. Also, you need to specify what kind of shell. Bash? Sh? Csh?

Comment: ok.. you must tell us more.. for your shell scripting, are you using bash?

Comment: Ron Thompson is right

Answer (score 1):

For Bash shell, this works fine

```
test -d XXXXX && echo "Ask what to do" || echo "Copy now"
```

And this is them example output.

```
% test -d hello && echo "Do something" || echo "Copy now"
Do something
% test -d hi && echo "Do something" || echo "Copy now"                        
Copy now
```

You have to change echo commant to the real command you need.